# Django User Model Oauth

Tags: django, model, oauth, token

I'm slightly new to Django, and I've never had a fun time doing user management in web dev. Is there a nice, basic example/tutorial on authentication the Django User model with Oauth such as Twitter?  Can I use the current User model and the data in it, or do I have to create a new table and migrate the current users over?

I tried searching around Google and such, and though I slightly see where alot of the django-social and oauth plugins go with things, I can't figure out how they're storing tokens and if they're extended to the User model.

In short, I just need a basic example and plain-English description on how to implement Oauth (or any login API) with the built-in Django User model.

Thanks!

Comment: check out https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2 , it has a django integration at the bottom :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) (the old deprecated version being [Django Social auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth)).

Comment: Combined with Paulo's link, this definitely helped with figuring out how these authentication systems work.  Thanks!